# Apple Push Notifications - two app id's and one server key

Tags: certificate, apple-push-notifications, push, pem, alerts

I am trying to deploy two applications that use apple push notifications. Both the applications talk to the same server application. Let us assume one is a a free version of the app and the other is a paid version - two different app IDs on the AppStore .

I would like build a single PEM key on the server that can be used to talk to the two different App IDs. I have been successfully able to use two separate PEM keys and have it talk to the apps separately but don't want to do this as its more of maintenance issue.

I am sure people have done this? Any ideas how I could combine the two private keys in the back end but have it talk to two App IDs?

Comment: possible duplicate of [APNS certificate issue for free and paid version](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18033263/apns-certificate-issue-for-free-and-paid-version)

Answer (score 0):

Afraid that is not possible.

Apple use the certificate to identify app(notification receiver).

You have to use two certificates, make two connections.