# APNS certificate issue for free and paid version

Tags: ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I have two Applications in iTunes. A free version and a paid version. The paid version does not have advertisement. The two versions have different App Ids.

I have set up APNS for one of the App Ids. How can I handle notifications for both Apps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each application requires its own certificate (since each App Id has its own push certificates).
Therefore, your server will have to hold a different certificate for each App, and maintain a separate connection with the APNs server for each App (since you use the certificate to open the connection).

This means that when one of your apps sends a device token to your server, you have to know which app sent the device token, and mark it accordingly in your DB (in order to know which connection to the APNs server to use when pushing a notification to that device).